# How to build the given data structure? Any name for it?

Tags: java, android

I have been given an `API` that saves data in a field in the following order:    `["Hello","world","confused"]` .

I don't know how to format like this before I pass my data as an input?
The text values are taken from a checkbox.
If I save it in an array I get `"[hello,world,confused]"` format.

Comment: That is because you save it as a single string, and not as an array. You have to use an array(`type[] array`) or list(`List<type> list` or `ArrayList<type> list`) or a map(`HashMap<keytype, type`)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question with sufficient and specific information to describe your problem such as code and error message.

Answer (score 0):

You save the raw values into a single String. YOu have to save it as an array, list or a map. I will not show map usage in this answer. Example:

```
//Get the Strings
String ex1 = "hello";
String ex2 = "world";
String ex3 = "confused";

//Array
String[] s = new String[3];
s[0] = ex1;
s[1] = ex2;
s[2] = ex3;
//List
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(ex1);
list.add(ex2);
list.add(ex3);
```

Now, if you send it over the internet and receive the data, send it as raw strings. Then convert it to List for easability. If the amount of Strings vary, this is the easiest way:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("[\"");

for(int i = 0; i < list.size()/*or .length if it is an array*/; i++){
    if(i == list.size() - 1)
        sb.append(list.get(i)/*or array[i]*/ + "\"]");
    else
        sb.append(list.get(i)/*or array[i]*/ + "\",\"");
}
String f = sb.toString();
//Display list: TextView, print to console, whatever you want to do
```

These are put in a List because it is much easier to loop a list than to manually add every String.

If the amount of Strings are static, you can use String.format:

```
String f = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "[\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\"]", ex1, ex2, ex3);
```

---

If I somehow misunderstood your question, let me know so I can edit my answer

Comment: Yea.. u understood it right.n looks like ur code cud work.. but i solved it...i added values to JsonArray when the check box is checked.n added it to jsonobject n send it to server with other data.Thank u for quick response